# List names of sheets in Google Sheets and skip the first two

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I found code to list the names of all the sheets in Google Sheets (from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Scru6M_86xw)):

```
function SheetNames() { // Usage as custom function: =SheetNames( GoogleClock() )
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;
  //out[0] = [ "Name" , "gid" ];
  for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i] = [sheets[i-1].getName()];
  return out
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}
```

My question is how can I modify the script to skip the first two sheet names and begin populating the list in the cell where the script is called?

I tried changing the `var i = 1` to `var i = 3` and that did skip the first two sheet names but it also created to blank cells. How do I skip the first two sheet names and not create any blank cells?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had the right idea, but your output array was placing the first item in position 3.  Instead, do this:

```
for (var i = 3 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i-2] = [sheets[i-1].getName()];
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I would have replied on the the original thread but it was closed - nice to get an answer from you!

Comment: note that it will die if the spreadsheet has less than 3 sheets.