# List all the names in a spreadsheet and skip the first few

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the following code to list all the names of sheets in a particular sheet.

```
function listSheetNames() {

    var names = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
        .map(function(s) {
            return [s.getName()];
        })

    //Sheet index where list needs to go
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1]
        .getRange(1, 1, names.length, names[0].length).setValues(names)
}
```

However I want to be able to skip the first few names so they dont get listed. How can this be done.

There is another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219679/list-names-of-sheets-in-google-sheets-and-skip-the-first-two) which shows this, but the code in that doesn't auto update, or is there a way of combining the two, without using the in cell formula from the one below.

And is there a way of inserting a link to the sheet when it lists.

```
function SheetNames() { // Usage as custom function: =SheetNames( GoogleClock() )
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;
  //out[0] = [ "Name" , "gid" ];
  for (var i = 3 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i-2] = [sheets[i-1].getName()];
  return out
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I managed to club the two together as follows

```
function listSheetNames() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
       .map(function(s) {
       return [s.getName()];
         }) 

    var out = new Array( ss.length+1 ) ;

  //out[0] = [ "Name" , "gid" ];
  for (var i = 3 ; i < ss.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i-2] = [ss[i-1].getName()];     

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1]
  .getRange(1, 1, sheets.length, sheets[0].length).setValues([out])

}
```

Now I get an error, If I make `.setValues([out])`

> incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 22 (line 46)

If I leave is as `.setValues(out)`

Then I get the error

> Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 46)

Comment: Check your range selection. I think you need to use `.getRange(1, 1, out.length, out[0].length)` since you need to select a range that is as big as the `out` array.

Comment: Tried that I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 46)"

Comment: Oh sorry, that was assuming `[0]` would have a value assigned and that's not the case. Try this instead: `.getRange(1, 1, out.length, out[1].length)` (since `out[1]` should contain a value). You could also just use this (since your array always has 1 column): `.getRange(1, 1, out.length, 1)`

Comment: Tried both, get the error "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 23 (line 46)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. I've added a link to the sheet in another column.
It puts the output in a tab called 'Output tab'.

```
function listSheetNames() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
       .map(function(s) {
       return s.getName();
         }) 
  var array = []
  for (var i = 3; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    array.push([sheets[i], '=hyperlink("'+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()+'#gid='+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[i]).getSheetId()+'"; "Linkname")']);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Output tab').getRange(1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array)
}
```

Comment: Anyway to link the listed item instead of a separate column with a linkname?

Comment: Figured it out

for (var i = 2; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    array.push([ '=hyperlink("'+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()+'#gid='+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[i]).getSheetId()+'"; "'+sheets[i]+'")']);

Thats a ton Casper, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be possible to do everything in the first loop (map)

```
function listSheetNames() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var array = ss.getSheets()
    .map(function (s) {
        return [s.getName(), '=hyperlink("' + ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + ss.getSheetByName(s.getName())
            .getSheetId() + '"; "Linkname")'];
    }).slice(2) //first two elements removed
ss.getSheetByName('Output tab')
    .getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length)
    .setValues(array)
}
```