# Difference between initializing array length and assign to index vs repeatedly pushing

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

While working on building a list of sheet names, I came across this question:
[List names of sheets in Google Sheets and skip the first two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219679/list-names-of-sheets-in-google-sheets-and-skip-the-first-two/)

Saving you the click, this person's solution is: (Stripped down, pseudo code)

```
getSheets() // Get all the sheets in spreadsheet workbook
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;

  for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ )
    out[i] = [sheets[i-1].getName()];
  return out
```

My solution would have leveraged:

```
...
var sheetName = sheet[i].getName();
out.push(sheetName);
```

The first solution seems to dynamically create empty array values, then later declare their value. While I have always just pushed new values into the array.

What is the difference?

In which situations is one better than the other?

In which situations should either be avoided?

Comment: Their solution creates a 2D array, yours is a 1D array (solely because they wrap the getName call in array literal brackets). Regarding the difference of behavior for array initialization, there are lots of refs out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array's length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the original code do quite different things.

Assuming `sheets` has objects in it that return the names `"sheet1"`, `"sheet2"`, and `"sheet3"` from `getName`, the original code creates an array that looks like this:

```
[
    (missing),
    ["sheet1"],
    ["sheet2"],
    ["sheet3"]
]
```

Note two things:

1. There is no entry at index 0. (It literally doesn't exist at all, which is *subtly* different from existing and containing the value `undefined`.)
2. The other entries are single-element *arrays*, each containing its sheet name.

Your code creates this instead:

```
[
    "sheet1",
    "sheet2",
    "sheet3"
]
```

Presumably the author had a reason for skipping index 0 and creating subordinate arrays (I'd guess because they were passing that result array into some API function that expects something in that form).

So there's no really a "better" or "worse" here, just different.

If your fundamental question is whether this:

```
var original = ["one", "two", "three"];
var updated = [];
for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
    updated[i] = original[i].toUpperCase(); // Or whatever
}
```

is better/worse than this:

```
var original = ["one", "two", "three"];
var updated = [];
for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
    updated.push(original[i].toUpperCase()); // Or whatever
}
```

the answer is: It's really a matter of style. Performance isn't markedly different between the two (and rarely matters), and amusingly one way is faster on some JavaScript engines and the other way is faster on others.

Both of those can probably be better expressed using `map`:

```
var original = ["one", "two", "three"];
var updated = original.map(function(entry) { return entry.toUpperCase(); });
```

I think Google Sheets has `map`, even though it mostly has only ES3-level features otherwise.

---

Side note: `new Array` is almost never the right way to create an array.